# How to replace old ceiling fan-light with just a light fixture

Tags: electrical, wiring

I would like to replace and old ugly ceiling fan-light in my dining room with a pendant type light. The original ceiling fan light was controlled by a dimmer switch on the wall and to operate the fan it was a pull chain. After taking down the fan and wiring the new light with what I thought were the correct wires, it still doesn't turn on. Does anyone know how to go about this?

I've attached pics of the wiring after I've pulled the fan down. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you now disconnected any wires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you have a standard switch loop, coming off the black bundle as white and returning as black. That return black, which is connected to the red wire, is your switched hot.

[image]

So...

- The white from your fixture goes to the white bundle (possibly without the jumper, which doesn't seem necessary).
- The black from the fixture goes to the single black wire (to which the red is now connected).
- The black from the fan that connects to the black bundle will simply be eliminated.

Make sure you have a good understanding of how to make safe connections with wire nuts, including the capacities of the different nut sizes.

Comment: I tried it and its still not working..... do you think its the dimmer switch? Should i replace it with a regular switch?

Comment: You shouldn't have accepted the answer if it didn't work. Sure... any device can fail. You can always nut the wires together to test.